# AG-GRID : External filter return rows based on multiple roles at once

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have a requirement, where I need to give them a radio button to see "Only my records", and based on there role, status will get filter , its working fine if user has single row , but in my case user can have multiple role in that case I need to add all those rows based on the role.

I am trying to use external filter but its not working can someone help me on this:

```
 doesExternalFilterPass(node) { 
    switch (selectedInvoiceStatus) {
                case 'MyRecord':
                    var mapping_data = (mapping as any).default;
                    var griddata=[];
                    personRole.forEach(element => {
                            var data= node.data.Status == mapping_data[element]
                            griddata.push(data)
                            node.data=griddata;
                    });
    
                    return  node.data;
    
                default:
                    return true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake I made was, I was send the filtered data in return statement. Later I realised that the return stament is for each row to show/hide based on returning bool value,I tried this and its working fine now

```
 switch (selectedInvoiceStatus) {
        case 'MyRecord':
          
            var bool=false;
            personRole.forEach(element => {
                        if(node.data.Status === element)
                        {bool= true}
                }
            });

            return bool;
        default:
            return false;
    }
```